# Smooth function with $f^{(n)}=0$ is polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, polynomials

> Let $I \subseteq \mathbb R$ be an interval and $f:I \to \mathbb R$ a function. Show that $f$ is a polynomial if and only if $f$ is smooth and there exists an $n \in \mathbb N$ so that $f^{(n)} = 0$.

I think I've got the forward direction:

Let $f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n a_n x^n$ be a polynomial. We know that monomials are differentiable and the derivative is a monomial with one degree less. Since a polynomial is only a linear combination of monomials and the derivative is linear, we have that polynomials are differentiable and the derivative is also a polynomial with one degree less. Therefore we get that $f^{(n)}$ exists and is a constant. Since the derivative of a constant function exists and is the zero function we get that $f^{(n+1)} = 0$. The zero function is differentiable with derivative the zero function, so we get that $f$ is smooth.

But I struggle with the reverse direction, where I have to show that $f$ is indeed no other function than a polynomial. I should make use of the following corollary: $f$ is constant iff $f$ is differentiable and $f'=0$.

Comment: You can prove this by induction, for example.

Comment: The latter condition is that $f^{(n)} \equiv 0$ on $I$, not that $f^{(n)}(x)$ for some specific point $x$. Just integrate to recover $f$; you know that $f$ is smooth.

Comment: @anomaly Yes, I indicated that $f^{(n)}$ is the zero function by not puting an "$(x)$" after it.

Comment: Yes, you wrote it correctly. My point is that since you know what $f^{n}$ is everywhere, you can integrate to recover $f$ (modulo polynomials of order $n-1$, as it turns out).

Comment: Use Taylor's theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let is prove that for all $n\geq1$ the following statement holds:

> $(P_n)$ if a smooth function $f$ is such that $f^{(n)}=0$, then $f$ is a polynomial.

The statement $(P_1)$ holds: if $f^{(1)}=0$, that is, if $f'=0$, then we know that $f$ is constant, so that it is a polynomial.

Suppose now that $(P_n)$ holds and let $f$ be a smooth function such that $f^{(n+1)}=0$. Then $g=f'$ is a smooth function such that $g^{(n)}=0$ and the fact that we are assuming that $(P_n)$ holds implies that $g$ is a polynomial. But then $f$, which is a primitive of $g$, is also a polynomial. We thus see that $(P_{n+1})$ holds if $(P_n)$ holds.